# Pass global data to views in sails js

Tags: sails.js

On my website I have a footer that has my last three blog posts. This is on every page. How can I pass this data to my template without having to pass it in every controller?

For example right now I am doing this in my controller:

```
  res.view({
    layout: "homeLayout",
    recent: posts
   });
```

But I dont want to have to pass recent in every res.view() call. How can I globally declare this data so its available to all views?

Comment: Here is my answer on the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20384451/1529893

Comment: Thanks, I've figured out a few ways to do this. The approach I took was basically the same except I didn't use res.locals, I put it directly in res (res.footerPosts) Why do you use res.locals? Any advantage?

Answer (score 1):

Create a for example configuration.js file in ./config folder with :

```
module.exports.configuration = {
    name: "amir",
};
```

Now , from anywhere you can access to varible for with :

```
sails.config.express.configuration
```

model , controller ,views ,service , ...